# xargs: unmatched single quote

Tags: linux, командная-строка

Удаляю все файлы `txt`, содержащие определенную подстроку:

```
find -name \*.txt | xargs grep -l ".(" | xargs rm -fr
```

Раньше команда работала, сейчас тот же сервер выдает следующую ошибку:

> xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: У какого-то файла в имени есть кавычка

Comment: @AlexeyTen, можно исключить такие файлы из поиска? Странно, не должно быть таких.

Comment: Но вообще, кажется всё вашу сложную конструкцию можно заменить одной командой `find -name '*?(*.txt' -delete`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, нужно, чтобы удалялись только те файлы, в тексте которых будет найдена определенная подстрока.

Comment: ой, туплю что-то на ночь

Comment: `find -name '*.txt' -execdir grep -qs '.(' '{}' ';' -delete`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо, это помогло.